# Question about an inequality with sequences

Tags: calculus, analysis

I'm thinking about a problem, and I want to be sure that I'm not wrong!

is it true or false that for any real convergent sequence $\{a_n\}$ ,
$$\lim_{n→∞}a_n≤\|a_n\|_\infty$$
where, $\|a_n\|_\infty=\sup_{n∈N}|a_n|$?

Comment: How can we say whether you are wrong if you don't tell us what you think the answer is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is true.

For each $m \in \mathbb N$, we have $a_m \le \|a_n\|_{\infty}$ (by definition of $\sup$). So, $\lim_{m \to \infty} a_m \le \|a_n\|_{\infty}$.

Comment: But was the OP right or wrong? You fell for it and probably answered a multiple choice question for him!

Comment: @RobArthan I really don't care about the OP. I just have an answer and I would like to share it.

Comment: MSE isn't intended to be a homework answering site.

Comment: actually I'm trying to prove something with Hahn-Banack, $\|, \|_\infty$ is my convex function

Comment: @TomBuilder: that's Banac**h**. Aside from that, if you needed the property to be true for your proof, you should have explained that in your question: "I want to be sure I'm not wrong" reads like "I don't want to lose points in my homework score" if you don't give your views or some context.

Answer (score 1):

Is true. Suppose that is false, then $c=\lim a_n>\vert a_k\vert $ for all $k\in\mathbb{N}$.

Now, exist $\epsilon>0$ such that $\vert a_k\vert \notin (c-\epsilon,c+\epsilon)$for all k, an absurd because $c$ is the limit of $a_n$